# Trying to better understand SSH -n -N -f flags

Tags: linux, ssh

I've been implementing some reverse SSH functions into a project I'm working on. In order to SSH directly to the remote device from my local laptop without first SSH'ing into the server (AWS instance in this case), I've been using the following command:

```
ssh -nfN -R 0.0.0.0:4444:localhost:22 user@remote_ip
```

The command is doing what I need it to, I just don't understand what exactly the `-f`, `-N`, `-n` commands are doing. I read the man page entries and even after that I am still not sure what they are doing.

Is `-f` backgrounding SSH at on the remote device or at the server, and why right "before command execution?" Why does it have to be included?

What does the man page entry for `-n` mean when it says "redirects stdin from /dev/null" - I know what /dev/null and stdin are, I just don't understand what specifically the "redirects" part means and why it is necessary. Why "must this be used to run SSH in the background?"

Why is `-N` necessary?

Appreciate the help. I just hate implementing things I read online without knowing what they are doing and why. So thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ssh+-nfN+-R+0.0.0.0%3A4444%3Alocalhost%3A22+user%40remote_ip). Does it explain anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-f` or `-n` options are backgrounding the `ssh` client to which they are given, ie. on your local laptop. (Option `-f` implies `-n`, so you actually only need one of the two.)

Backgrounding is done so you get a new shell prompt, allowing you to enter further commands, even though the `ssh` command continues to run in order to maintain the tunnel. Without backgrounding, the terminal window in which you entered the `ssh` command would remain blocked while the tunnel is running, and you'd have to open another terminal window to be able to enter other commands.

A process which is running in the background does not have access to the terminal (`/dev/tty`), so its standard input, output, and error need to be connected (redirected) to something else. In the case of `ssh` being run just for creating a tunnel, no input or output is necessary anyway, so `/dev/null` is the natural device to connect them to.

Option `-N` tells `ssh` not to try reading a command from standard input which, being connected to `/dev/null`, would return EOF and thereby terminate the tunnel immediately.

Option `-f` is necessary if `ssh` needs to ask for a password or passphrase for the connection, which it cannot do if it is already backgrounded. If your `ssh` command is able to connect without any input from you, `-n` would suffice, but `-f` won't hurt, so it's fine to always use it regardless whether it is really needed.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this amazing answer. It clears up the command perfectly and I understand what it's doing now. Really appreciate the help!